# Compile oct file with fortran openmp using LDFLAGS

Tags: fortran, openmp, octave

Using ubuntu 14.04 octave 3.8.1.
I'm attempting to create an .oct file which makes use of multithreaded fortran program. However, mkoctfile fails to use the related libraries during linking.

The files I'm using look as follows:
c:

```
#include <octave/oct.h>
extern "C" {
void fort5();
}

DEFUN_DLD (ce5, args, ,"help here")
{
fort5();
}
```

fortran:

```
subroutine fort5() bind(c)
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
!$OMP PARALLEL
    write(*,*) "Hello"
!$OMP END PARALLEL 
end subroutine fort5
```

I expect this code to result in output of four lines of "Hello".
I compile it with following command
    mkoctfile CPP.cpp FORTRAN.f90
As a result I get only one output line, which indicates multitrhreading was ignored.

When compiled outside octave (with minor alterations to c++ file) with following command:

```
gcc -c CPP.cpp && gfortran -Wall -fimplicit-none -Wtabs -fdefault -real-8 -fopenmp  -c FORTRAN.f90 &&gfortran -fopenmp -o3 CPP.o FORTRAN.o -lstdc++ -o OUT.out
```

The result is as it should be.

From several tests it becomes apparent, that mkoctfile is not capable to use -fopenmp flag in any form. As found [on the internet](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/mkoctfile-and-OpenMP-td4561550.html) this should be solvable by using LDFLAGS, however, for some reason I fail at that.

I set the enviroment variable in octave terminal with
    setenv("LDFLAGS","-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions, -Wl,-z,relro, -fopenmp")
    setenv("FFLAGS","-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fopenmp")
the $mkoctfile --print LDFLAGS indicates that the variable was set successfully. However, the compiled function fails to load: $undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel_start

I've tried explicitly listing the library but the result was the same.

```
mkoctfile ce5.cpp fort5.o '-Wl,-fopenmp' '-l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
mkoctfile ce5.cpp fort5.o '-Wl,-fopenmp' '-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'
```

Did I use the flags correctly? What else should I do to get correct compilation?

Comment: Always use tag fortran. Add version tags only when it is necessary to use a specific version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:
Seems like consecutive application of the following commands done the trick:

```
setenv("FFLAGS","-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fopenmp")
setenv("LDFLAGS","-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions, -Wl,-z,relro, -Wl,-fopenmp")
mkoctfile ce5.cpp fort5.o  '-L, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1'
```

Most likely the problem was setting correct flag for compiler ($-fopenmp in FFLAGS) and correct indication of library location.